# Saving functions in .m file(s)

Tags: save

Suppose that I have the function `f[a][x_]:= x^2` and I want to save it in a .m file, then if I do `Save["/path/",{x,f[a]}]` doesn't work.

My first question is why it doesn't work and the second is what is actually the first argument of the f, i.e. the `[a]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use symbols or lists of symbols as the second argument of [`Save`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Save). So for:

```
f[a][x_] := x^2
```

you would use:

```
Save["test.m", f]
```

Check:

```
Import["test.m", "String"]
```

> "f[a][x_] := x^2
>   "